# How to get markdown to work within multiple ReactJS components

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new to reactJS and I've run into a problem for which I need some help. I have searched and searched to sort this out myself but couldn't. *(I read through rendering multiple components - but it's not the solution to the problem I have here)*

**Here's a description of what I am trying to do.**

My render function calls a certain component named 'Board'. This is the parent component which displays the child component, 'Notes'. On rendering Board, at the click of a button on the page, notes are added on screen (something like sticky yellow notes). Please see attached image to help

The problem however is I am trying to  support the use of markdown text within these Yellow Notes which are randomly positioned on screen BUT everything I've done isn't working. Here's the code below and I explain somethings I've tried in the code comments too...

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import marked from 'marked';
    import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import './App.css';

    var Note = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
    return {editing: false};
    },

    componentWillMount() {
    //randomly place the notes on Board and rotate them
    this.style = {
    right: this.randBtw(0, window.innerWidth - 150) + 'px', //150 = note size
    top: this.randBtw(0, window.innerHeight - 150) + 'px',
    transform: 'rotate(' + this.randBtw(-15, 15) + 'deg)'
    };
    },

    randBtw(min, max) {
    //generate random numbers to be used in positioning the notes within the browser window
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    },

   edit() {
   this.setState({editing: true});
   },

   rawMarkup() {
   return {__html: marked(this.props.children)};
   },

   save() {
   //i tried this: I tried getting (this.refs.textarea.value) and parsing it via markdown. However i figured out 
//that I couldn't since the ref, "textarea" since it existed on a different state. I guess that's the reason

  this.props.onChange(this.refs.textarea.value, this.props.index); //this is where the index passed unto Board comes to play
  this.setState({editing: false});
  },

  remove() {
  this.props.onRemove(this.props.index);
  },

  displayEditing() {
  return (
  <div className='note' style={this.style}> 
    <textarea ref='textarea' defaultValue={this.props.children} className='form-control'></textarea>
    <button onClick={this.save} className='btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'/>
  </div>
  );
  },

  displayDefault() {
  //I tried this: remove this.props.children and do dangerouslySetInnerHTMl = {this.rawMarkup()}...
  return (
  <div className="note" style={this.style}>
      <p>{this.props.children}</p>
       <span>
          <button onClick={this.edit} className='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'/>
          <button onClick={this.remove} className='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash'/>
       </span>
  </div>
  );
  },
  render() {
  if (this.state.editing) {
  return this.displayEditing();
  }else {
  return this.displayDefault();
  }
  }
  })

 var Board = React.createClass({
 propTypes: {
 count: function(props, propName) {
  if (typeof props[propName] !== 'number') {
    return new Error('The count property must be a number');
  }
  if (typeof props[propName] > 100) {
    return new Error('Creating' + props + ' notes doesn\'t make sense');
  }
 }
 },
 getInitialState() {
 return {
  notes: []
 };
},

nextId() {
this.uniqueId = this.uniqueId || 0;
return this.uniqueId++;
},

remove(i) {
var arr = this.state.notes; //store state of notes 
arr.splice(i, 1);
this.setState({notes: arr});
},

add(text) {
//see bind in render fxn. This sets the default 'text' to 'new notes'
var arr = this.state.notes;
arr.push({
  id: this.nextId(),
  note: text
 });
 this.setState({notes:arr});
},

update(newText, i) {
var arr = this.state.notes; //store state of notes
arr[i].note = newText;
this.setState({notes: arr});
},

 eachNote(note, i) {
 return (
      //pass in props. Also index is quite important so exact Note can be accessed by Note
        <Note 
          key={note.id} 
          index={i} 
          onChange={this.update} 
          onRemove={this.remove}
        >{note.note}</Note> //TODO: remove child {note.note} ??
        );
    },

 render() {
  return (
    <div className='board'>
      {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
      <button onClick={this.add.bind(null, 'New Note')} className='btn btn-sm btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus '/>
    </div>
  )
  }
 })

class App extends Component {
 render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <Board count={120}/>
  </div>
 );
 }
 }

 export default App;
```

[animated gif showing the problem encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/busEG.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a go and following should work.

Change this line:

```
<p>{this.props.children}</p>
```

to something like this:

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()}/>
```

[image]

Comment: My goodness...I thought I had done that before (I even included it in the comments) BUT it worked now! I must have missed something, thanks a lot Adrian